# knockoutjs 'Cart editor' example questions

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to understand how the variables are observed and mapped. The jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/adNuR/. The following 2 lines of javascripts seem to set up the variables for observation:

```
this.category = ko.observable();
this.product = ko.observable();
```

So how do the above 2 lines do the tricks? How does it know how to map the category and product into the sampleProductCategories[] array?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle loads a resource that contains all of the choices that live in the `sampleProductCategories` array: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/sampleProductCategories.js

Each `cartLine` object has `category` and `product` observables to hold the current choice.

For example, here is one of the bindings for the individual cartLine:

```
<select data-bind='options: sampleProductCategories, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: category' />
```

This says that the options in the dropdown should come from `sampleProductCategories`.  The value in the box should be the `name` property and when a selection is made, it should be put into the `category` of the cartLine.

So, when a selection is made, `category` now equals the appropriate object from the `sampleProductCategories` array.  Something like:

```
{
    "products": [{
        "name": "1950's Chicago Surface Lines Streetcar",
        "price": 26.72
    }, {
        "name": "1962 City of Detroit Streetcar",
        "price": 37.49
    }, {
        "name": "Collectable Wooden Train",
        "price": 67.56
    }],
    "name": "Trains"
}
```

Now, the second dropdown binding looks like:

```
<select data-bind='visible: category, options: category() ? category().products : null, optionsText: "name", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: product' />
```

This binding shows up if a category has been selected.  The options come from the `products` array of the selected category.  When a value is selected, then the `product` observable will be populated with the appropriate object from the array.  Like:

```
{
     "name": "Collectable Wooden Train",
     "price": 67.56
}
```

So, the dropdowns work together to provide nested options.

Comment: Thanks much Ryan. That was real helpful. Now I realize that it's the 'data-bind' that actually assigns the variables!