# ko.obervable is getting updated twice

Tags: knockout.js

My view model has few observable properties, I am using them to store values from dropdown its basically like the cart example explained here.

[knockoutjs 'Cart editor' example questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881235/knockoutjs-cart-editor-example-questions)

here's my html
1)select boardtest
2)select scores for each section

```
<select data-bind="options :$parent.boardTestData,optionsText:'name', value:boardTestSelected, optionsCaption:'Select Test' ">     </select>
   <div data-bind="visible : boardTestSelected, foreach : boardTestSelected() ? boardTestSelected().testParts : null">
   <div>
        <span  data-bind="text: boardTestPartName"></span>
        <select data-bind="options: testPartValues, optionsText:'BoardTestPartValue',
         value: $parent.testPartValueSelected> </select>   
   </div>
   </div>
```

My view model has

$parent.boardTestData is an obervablearray() with array of type testParts[]
and testParts contains another array testPartValues[]

```
class @BoardTestData
    constructor :(data) ->
        @id = data.Id
        @name = data.Name
        @testParts = []
        @testParts.push new TestParts data.Name,d for d in data.TestParts

class @TestParts
    constructor:(partData) ->
        @testPartValues = []
class @TestPartValues
    constructor:(partValues) ->                 
        @BoardTestPartValueId= partValues.Id
        @BoardTestPartValue = partValues.Value      


@boardTestSelected = ko.observable()
@testPartSelected = ko.observable()
@testPartValueSelected =  ko.observable()
```

I have subscribe on testPartValueSelected  and its being executed twice first time with correct values and then witj null value, so I think there is something thats setting @testPartValueSelected to null or undefined.

- it somehow works fine when there is just a single item in the foreach for the nested dropdown

and while I am doing this the other question that I have is it possible to push the selected values from dropdown to an array or obersvable array() ?

Set up the JS Fiddle for this issue :  http://jsfiddle.net/paisley/W82yE/11/

Comment: Could you provide a proper javascript example? I don't know what that code is but it doesn't look much like javascript to me :(

Answer (score 0):

When you give @BoardTestData a value, the subscription is hit.  This is because knockout automatically assigns the `value` of the drop down to the first value.  You've set your value as the `testpartvalueselected` variable so that gets set.

Later on you set it again as a new ko.observable().  knockout detects the change once again and hits the subscription.

When you assign values to a drop down list, you do not need to manually set the according "selected" value.  It is already set for you.

Comment: ok so the 3 classes that I have mentioned in the above code are just for the static data when the page loads first time. The UI allows you to add boardtest and all that stuff is taken care of in a seperate class, and that class defines the 3 obersavble properties mentioned above to store the values of the dropdown.
so when you select a boardtest I expect it to set boardTestSelected and fire its subscribe, when you select value for nested dropdown I expect testPartValueSelected to be set,which it does but immediately after that its being set to null.so howz the second change getting fired?